# Where can I download original OpenGL SDK (not GLUT) for WindowsXP?

Tags: opengl, windows-xp, download

Where can I download original OpenGL SDK (not GLUT) for WindowsXP?

I don't have any extra graphics accelerator card installed on my PC. I have just a built-in card.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't it install with visual studio?

If not try the platform sdk

IIRC Windows itself only ships with OpenGL1.1, almost all cards support at least 2.  You can download the newer SDKs from the card makers. Generally NVidia have the best and most complete OpenGL on Windows

Comment: Windows SDK is OpenGL1.1 - if you want newer than that then you are probably going to need the SDK from a particular graphics card. Since on windows the opengl drivers that work are NVidia you might as well just use their opengl SDK

Comment: edit your answer so that your comment stays on top. It is more useful than the answer itself.